# IE8 Excanvas Not Working: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-8

So I am including the line below:

```
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

I get the error "`Object doesn't support this property or method`"

```
confetti.Context = function(parent) {
        var i = 0;
        var canvasParent = document.getElementById(parent);
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = canvasParent.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = canvasParent.offsetHeight;
        canvasParent.appendChild(canvas);
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
```

The error comes at the point mentioned above. I've got through various SO questions/answers but couldn't find a suitable solution.

Unfortunately IE8 is what we still use so have to find a workaround, even if it it means not running the script

Thanks

Comment: What exact line is throwing that error. Also, if you are running multiple versions of IE, you'll want this: `[if IE]` to be this: `[if lte IE 8]` to only target IE 8 and less. You probably should change that even if you only run IE 8 right now, because when you upgrade in the future, your code will always load the fallback.

Comment: The one where it's commented that the error happens there. I'm using the code to target all of IE for now to make sure IE8 is included.

Comment: Using my suggestion will still ensure that it runs with IE 8 and is the recommended code from the Execanvas team. Make sure that command is in your code prior to the JS code. See: https://github.com/arv/ExplorerCanvas/commit/5dc81e8affaf8fcc5ca4c8302b8e41682ddc8dda for an example.

Comment: Afraid not. The line is right at the top between my <head> tags and my JavaScript is down the bottom toward the footer

Comment: I would suggest you try the sample provided by the Execanvas team (at the link I shared earlier). If you can get that to work, you'll just need to make modifications to it. If that doesn't work either, you'll know you have a deeper issue.

Comment: try G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas) before getContext.

Comment: I redownloaded the file and it worked - seems whatever copy I had was corrupt!